# How to make 'Continue with Facebook' button for web mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, facebook-javascript-sdk

I recently added a continue with facebook button to my webapp using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button to provide button code. I've noticed that this button is not dynamic in size and looks horrible on mobile devices - can anyone point me in the direction of a fix to make it more mobile friendly. I'm using the large button, i.e.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" 
data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Size `large` is described as resulting in a width of between 240 and 400 pixels. (It also says “Custom Widths” were available, but doesn’t specify what exactly that means.) Perhaps you need to use one of the smaller sizes on mobile dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was to use my own button and control it's action using JS.

and then on button click, make the call.

```
FB.login(function(response){
   // Do what you want here
});
```